# Is it possible to export MultiClassification model in Python with Catboost?

Tags: python, model, multiclass-classification, catboost

I am trying to save my MultiClassification model in Python.

I know that currently Catboost currently does not support saving MultiClassification models in Python.

Are there any workarounds to this, if I want to save and apply this model do I have to use Java or something else?

```
model1.save_model('../model', pool=train_dataset , format="python")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you could set format="cbm" to save it in binary format.

Comment: You should prefer binary format to other formats, since the model in this format is much smaller and predictions are faster.